# how to create a page.tpl.php without $page['content']?

Tags: nodes, 7

The `page.tpl.php` of my website shouldn't contain `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` because it is only set of blocks. The problem is I'm not able to insert comment form into node pages of a website which its `page.tpl.php` hasn't `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` . what shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked simple question & there is very simple answer for that --

Yes, you can create `page.tpl.php` without `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`. You just have to remove this snippet from the TPL file & it will work.

But then you have explained your issue about comment.

So if you go through the structure of tpl files at theme, you will understand that `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` is responsible to print `node.tpl.php` & that one contains `<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>`.

So without fetching the things of `node.tpl.php` you won't get comments. Anyway, how a comment can be associated to a page when there is no node.

Comment: thanks for your useful reply. so what is your idea, what if I only want to have a set of blocks in the front page of website? this is my idea: prevent all the contents from being promoted to the front page. any other idea?

Comment: Many people do that for front page. You just make a tpl named page--front.tpl.php & remove the snippet for content. Use other regions, which ever is required. Clear the cache & you are ready to go..